# get rid of navigation bar in view controller iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, xcode4

I am basically creating an app that looks like a power point presentation. every time the user clicks on a button I add another view controller. So here is what I have:

This is the ViewController that I want to add when the user want's to go to the next slide:

[image]

I have a button that when clicked it shows this view controller. In this example it will show nothing because the view controller is empty.

[image]

so when that code get's fired this is what happens with my iPad:

[image]

It loads that view controller perfectly fine but with the navigation bar at the top. How could I get rid of that navigation bar? I think the problem is the code because the view controller is empty. I know just the basics of objective-c so I have not been able to fix it with code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert this line of code before presenting your navigation controller modally:

```
[navControl setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```